# Interpolating a variable passed into a JS function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating a function like so:

```
function ajaxinate(divId) {
  ('divId .anotherDiv').toggle();
}
```

Can someone please tell me how to decorate the divId parameter within the function so that it interpolates from what's passed in?  For example, when I call

```
ajaxinate('#myAjaxinatedDiv');
```

I would like the function to look like:

```
('#myAjaxinatedDiv .anotherDiv').toggle();
```

For some reason, I can't get the variable assigned as divID to interpolate into the function.  I've tried decorating divId with singe quotes and + signs and just about every possible combination of the sort...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass in the variable to the string:

```
function ajaxinate(divId) {
  $(divId + ' .anotherDiv').toggle();
}
```

(Also, I'm assuming you meant to use `$` for jQuery.)

Comment: Thanks!  Comedy of errors on my end and that's what I get for working on Sunday!

Comment: Show me what you did -- http://jsfiddle.net (paste into the JS section, save, and send me the link)

Comment: @AngeloChrysoulakis That's fine. Can you show me how you called the function so I can see what went wrong? :)

Comment: Thanks for your help David - In the function definition I used div_id and then in the function I used divId.  Your response helped me figure out the problem (originally, I was trying to interpolate divId by using '+ divId +' which did not work.

Comment: That was my first official SO question.  I just accepted your answer David.  Thanks again for the great assist!